Logical Volume Management in Linux (Ubuntu)
I'm encountering an issue with my virtual machine. Initially, I allocated 25 GB of storage to it, installed Docker, Jenkins, and several other applications, and extended the LVM to 18 GB. Now, I'm facing a space crunch as I need to publish my latest build. I expanded the storage from Hyper-V to 70 GB, but I'm unable to extend my LVM to match the new size. Can you please guide me on how to extend my volume?
sudo vgs
  VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- 18.22g 228.00m

 df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                               86M  1.6M   85M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   18G   14G  3.5G  80% /
tmpfs                              429M     0  429M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/sda2                          1.8G  252M  1.4G  16% /boot
tmpfs                               86M  4.0K   86M   1% /run/user/1001

When I run lsblk, it shows 60 GB:
sda                         8:0    0    60G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0   1.8G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0  18.2G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0    18G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom


There are two ways to do this.
The first is to create a new partition in the unused space that must exist on sda and add that to your volume group. This tutorial covers what you need to do. https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/
The second is to resize sda3 and then follow the steps in the answer to this question. Extend vg-ubuntu--lv after adding space in vSphere

Thank you, @PonJar, for your support!
